# MSAL. Application freeze on WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, azure-ad-msal

**Task:** I need to create an interactive login through the separate WPF window, which MSAL(Microsoft.Identity.Client) has to show me.
Solution: The following piece of code should solve my task.

```
            IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(_publicClientApplicationOptions).WithDefaultRedirectUri().Build();
            byte[] exchangeCache = null;
            publicClientApplication.UserTokenCache.SetAfterAccess(tokenCacheArgs =>
            {
                exchangeCache = tokenCacheArgs.TokenCache.SerializeMsalV3();
            });

            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            Task<AuthenticationResult> task = publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(_ewsScopes).WithParentActivityOrWindow(GetWindowHandle()).ExecuteAsync();
            result = task.Result; // this line gots freeze
```

**Problem:** The last line of code provokes a freeze of code and application at all.

I tried to `task.Start()`, but it throws an exception, and separate Window appears.

**Question:** Is there a way to solve the "freeze problem"? And how to do it?

UPD: Solved it

```
Task<AuthenticationResult> task = Task.Run(() => publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(_ewsScopes).WithParentActivityOrWindow(GetWindowHandle()).ExecuteAsync());
```

Comment: Thank you! Your UPD helped me with a similar problem where I called AcquireTokenInteractive this way:
bool bResult = publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive()...ExecuteAsync().Result;
When calling this from a WinForm dialog, this call hangs. With your UPD it runs smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

You should [await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) the task asynchronously instead of accessing the blocking `Result` property:

```
AuthenticationResult result = await publicClientApplication
  .AcquireTokenInteractive(_ewsScopes)
  .WithParentActivityOrWindow(GetWindowHandle())
  .ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: I need to use it synchoniously, but solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You encounter a deadlock by waiting synchronously for the result of the authentication task. The problem is *continuation*. Each thread runs in a *context*. In `ExecuteAsync` a task is awaited and when it completes, the method continues execution in the current context, which is the UI context in your example. Since the operation takes a while, an incomplete task is returned to `ExecutedAsync` and the UI context is captured. Now, the task returned to your method is incomplete, too, and by `task.Result` you synchronously wait for it to finish in the UI context. Then, when the task finally completes, the `ExecuteAsync` method cannot continue running on the captured UI context, because it is blocked by waiting for the result of the task.

Stephen Cleary has a great, comprehensive blog series about async/await and the issues that you can encounter. He describes this issue in detail [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and you should really have a look at it. To quote him:

> Don’t block on Tasks; use async all the way down.

Other options include using `ConfigureAwait`, however to quote him as an expert on this topic again:

> Using ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlock is at best just a hack).